# In the google drive search api, how to group words into a phrase?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive search api with the [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)  - [search for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters).

I have a query like : `fullText contains 'battle of hastings'`.

I'm getting results that seem to suggest that it searches for the individual words, rather than the phrase as a whole. I'm not completely clear though, and am relating the API's functionality to what can be done on a Google Search via the website, so please correct me there.

Anyway, I really only want results for the whole phrase - ie like surrounding a phrase in Google's Search web site with double quotes. For example, if you use Google's search web site to search for `"no one will have written this before"`, then it says `'No results found for "no one will have written this before".'`, but if you don't use double quotes, then you get all sort of stuff.

To summarise:

1. Does the query api search for individual words and only return files with all those words in, even if they're not as a phrase, or in that order?
2. Is there a way to make it consider the words as a single phrase?

Comment: It should be searching on the full string.  I just tested it and it only returned one.

Answer (score 0):

By using the try section of [Files:List](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) and consulting the [search parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) documentation.

```
fullText - Full text of the file including title, description, and content.
contains - The content of one string is present in the other.
```

I tested using this

```
fullText contains 'daimto twitter'
```

It returned all of the files that contain that exact match.

Answer (score 0):

By using the try it facility, I found that the behaviour is similar to the search ui in google drive, and you need to surround phrases that are to be considered one with double quotes. The quotes should be encoded into the URL like this :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=100&
q=fullText+contains+'%22flippity+floppity%22'
```

I'm not sure if the spaces need to be encoded like that, but I tried to emulate it as much as possible.